# two way data binding in angular2 from parent component to child component

Tags: data-binding, angular

I am passing an object from parent to child. 
In child I am making changes to this object.
Now , whenever I am making a change to this object in child, It should reflect in parent.
For ex.
while loading child component :

```
<child [record]="record"></child>
```

Now when I am changing record in child.I want it to reflect in parent.

any way to achieve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not reassigning `record` in the child – i.e., you are not doing something like `this.record = newRecord;` – then what you have should work fine.

Since you are passing a JavaScript reference type (an object) to the child, any changes you make to the properties of the object in the child – e.g., `this.record.property1 = someNewValue;` – will be "seen" by the parent because both the parent and the child have a reference to the same `record` object.  There is only one `record` object that is being manipulated.

If you are reassigning `record` in the child (or if `record` was instead a primitive type such as an integer, string, or boolean), then see @Günter's answer.  In this case, there are multiple `record` objects involved, so you have to tell the parent when the child starts using a new object.

Answer (score 5):

The child component needs an `@Input()` and `@Output()` for two-way binding to work

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  ...
})
export component MyChild {
  @Input() record;
  @Output() recordChange = new EventEmitter();

  updateRecord(newRecord) {
    this.record = newRecord;
    this.recordChange.emit(this.record);
  }
}
```

For `[(record)]="...."` to work it is important that input and output have the same base name ('record') and the output has the suffix `Change` otherwise you would need to longer syntax

```
[record]="..." (recordUpdated)="..."
```

(assuming the output is named `recordUpdated`)

Comment: can you provide a source for this information about having the same base name and the suffix `Change`?

Comment: The docs mention it. That part was added a few weeks ago. Sorry only on the phone. I guess it's mentioned somewhere near template syntax or two-way-binding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the banana in the box syntax:

```
 <child [(record)]="record"></child>
```