# Angular2 way to update data in nested component from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have two nested components: `grid-container` and `grid-component`.

In `grid-container`, the `grid-component` is initialized as follows:

```
<grid [title]="'This is the grid title'" [data]="data"></grid>
```

Data is initialized. Using events, the updated `data` in `grid-component` can  be obtained in `grid-container`. Its obvious until here for me. However, what should we typically do in angular 2 to update `data` in the nested component (`grid-component` in this case) from the container component (`grid-container`)?

More specifically, (or as an illustration) I need a function that adds an item in container component (`grid-container`) which will be applied in `data` in `grid-component`

*ps: its not two-way data binding as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811333/two-way-data-binding-in-angular2-from-parent-component-to-child-component) which also didn't work for this problem.*

**EDIT:**

```
export class GridComponent{ //child component
  @Input() data:any;
}

import { GridComponent } from 'somewhere';
export class GridContainer{ //parent component
  data:any = [{/*an initialized object which is visible in child component*/}]

  addItem(){
    data.push({/*an item is added*/};
    //PROBLEM IS THE NEWLY ADDED ITEM IS NOT VISIBLE IN GridComponent class.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but maybe if someone get here will see solution. I think the best solution for this is `service` which provide easy and clear way to pass data. In your case the child's should `subscribe` an `observable` and in parent component you should use service method to pass data whenever you want to update data in child's components. Example below. Also look at the [angular 2 cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

**Parent component**

```
export class GridContainer {
   constructor(private GridService: GridService) {  }
   private data: any[] = [];
   private addItem(el) {
      this.data.push(el);
      this.GridService.pushGridData(this.data);
   }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor(private GridService: GridService) {  }
   private data: any[] = [];
   private subscribtion: Subscribtion;
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.Subscribtion = this.GridService.gridData.subscribe(
         (data) => { this.data = data; }
      )
   }
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.Subscribtion.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable();
export class GridService {
   constructor() {  }

   private gridDataSource = new Subject<any[]>()

   gridData = this.gridDataSource.asObservable();

   pushGridData(data) {
      this.gridDataSource.next(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Please provide example of your HTML.
If you have Parent-Child relation, then it is 2 way databinding.

```
@Component({
    template:`
        <grid-component>
            <grid-component [(data)]="gridData"></grid-component>
            <input type="button" label="Update Parent" (click)="updateData()" />
            <label>{{gridData.someCounter}}</label>
        </grid>
    `
})
class GridComponent{
    gridData: any = {
        someCounter = 1;
    };

    updateData() {
        this.gridData.someCounter++;
    }
}

@Component({
    template:`
        <input type="button" label="Update Child" (click)="updateData()" />
        <label>data.someCounter</label>
    `
})
class GridContainerComponent{
    @Input() data: any;
    @Output() dataChange = new EventEmitter();

    //You must trigger this method from GridContainer somehow. E.g. on button click
    updateData() {
        this.data.someCounter++;
        //this row is the most important, and you have to call it manually each time you want to prompt new value to parent. 
        //I.e. in another place you can update 'this.data' but do not update that value in Parent just skipping this line.
        this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
    }
}
```

If you have 2 Siblings, then it is still 2 way databinding where Parent serves as Proxy:

```
<grid>
    <grid-component [(dataChild1)]="dataParent"></grid-component>
    <grid-container [(dataChild2)]="dataParent"></grid-container>
</grid>
```

Or you can use Service [Sibling Component Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)

Comment: I think you have misunderstand my question. My question is updated with minimal ts code. html part to initialize was alredy given.

Comment: Please add your templates for `GridComponent` and `GridContainer`. You have too many definitions. Provided template shows `<grid>`, but how it is combined with `<grid-component>` and `<grid-container>` is not clear. More over, if you use `Array` it will be updated in Parent and Child even without 2 way databinding (see SuperParent to Parent relationship). https://plnkr.co/edit/VxfkUKGNYaL5QHBxuCR2?p=preview